# Pass Array using Web services in Ksoap2

Tags: java, web-services, ksoap2

I have to call a web service in which web service is called by kSoap2 method, now in this one node is a Array so how i can pass it.

```
POST /opera/OperaWS.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 182.71.19.26
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/SendGroupMessageNotification"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendGroupMessageNotification xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <reciverMemberId>
        <Group>
          <groupid>string</groupid>
          <groupMembers>
            <Id>string</Id>
            <Id>string</Id>
          </groupMembers>
        </Group>
        <Group>
          <groupid>string</groupid>
          <groupMembers>
            <Id>string</Id>
            <Id>string</Id>
          </groupMembers>
        </Group>
      </reciverMemberId>
      <MemberId>int</MemberId>
      <MESSAGE>string</MESSAGE>
      <CREATEDDATE>string</CREATEDDATE>
      <isUrgent>boolean</isUrgent>
      <Predifnemessage>string</Predifnemessage>
    </SendGroupMessageNotification>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So in the above web service, how i can i set the values for the reciverMemberId

remaining parameters is set easily with the propertyInfo.

For this i made some code as below

```
static class Group implements KvmSerializable
    {
        String groupid;
        Vector groupMembers;
        public Group(String groupId,Vector groupmembers)
        {
            this.groupid=groupId;
            this.groupMembers=groupmembers;
        }

        public Object getProperty(int i)
        {
            switch(i)
            {
                case 0:
                    return groupid;
                case 1:
                    return groupMembers;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public int getPropertyCount()
        {
            return 2;
        }

        public void setProperty(int i, Object o)
        {
            switch(i)
            {
                case 0:
                    groupid=o.toString(); break;
                case 1:
                    groupMembers=(Vector) o;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void getPropertyInfo(int i, Hashtable hshtbl, PropertyInfo pi)
        {
            switch(i)
            {
                case 0:
                    pi.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    pi.name="groupid";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    pi.type=PropertyInfo.VECTOR_CLASS;
                    pi.name="groupMembers";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    static class RereciverMemberId implements KvmSerializable
    {

        Group grp;
        public RereciverMemberId()
        {
            Vector grpMembers=new Vector();
            grpMembers.add("29");
            grpMembers.add("36");
            grp=new Group("1", grpMembers);
        }
        public Object getProperty(int i)
        {
            return grp;
        }

        public int getPropertyCount()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public void setProperty(int i, Object o)
        {
            this.grp=(Group) o;
        }

        public void getPropertyInfo(int i, Hashtable hshtbl, PropertyInfo pi)
        {
            pi.type=grp.getClass();
            pi.name="Group";
        }

    }
    public static void sendGroupMessageNotification()
    {
        SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/SendGroupMessageNotification";
        METHOD_NAME="SendGroupMessageNotification";
        SoapObject myObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

        //String str="<Group><groupid>1</groupid><groupMembers><Id>29</Id><Id>36</Id></groupMembers></Group>";
        RereciverMemberId rec=new RereciverMemberId();
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("reciverMemberId");
        pi.setValue(rec);
        pi.setType(rec.getClass());
        myObject.addProperty(pi);
        PropertyInfo p = new PropertyInfo();
        p.setName("MemberId");
        p.setValue(1);
        p.setType(PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(p);
        p = new PropertyInfo();
        p.setName("MESSAGE");
        p.setValue("Test Message From JAVA");
        p.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(p);

        p = new PropertyInfo();
        p.setName("CREATEDDATE");
        p.setValue("15 Dec 2011");
        p.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(p);

        p = new PropertyInfo();
        p.setName("isUrent");
        p.setValue(false);
        p.setType(PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(p);

        p = new PropertyInfo();
        p.setName("Predifnemessage");
        p.setValue("Hello");
        p.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(p);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(myObject);
        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try
        {
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SoapWebServices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SoapWebServices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try
        {
                SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                System.out.println(result.toString());
        }
        catch (SoapFault ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SoapWebServices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using Jax? You would just make a class containing a List (=your array) and annotate it accordingly.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html
Wait, I'll write an answer ...

Comment: ok thank u for writing answer

Comment: Awh, just saw that I mixed that up. For kSoap JaxB might not work ...

Comment: I have the same problem, and I've been searching for an answer for a long time, but nothing. The most I could get is pass a complex object inside in another complex object, and pass an array of complex objects (but not an array inside in a complex object).

Comment: hey all thank to all of you, but now i implement the correct way of how we pass the complex object in Soap

Comment: I put the answer to anyone who needs it, again thanks to all

Answer (score 7):

This can be done by making different SoapObject of corresponding Node, so like in the above problem we have to make two soap objects one for Group, and other for GroupMembers.

entire code

```
public static String sendGroupMessageNotification(ArrayList<String>          
groupIdList,ArrayList<String> members,String senderId,String messageText,boolean isUrgentFlag)
    {
        SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/SendGroupMessageNotification";
        METHOD_NAME = "SendGroupMessageNotification";

        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
        SoapObject myObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapObject groupSoap=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        SoapObject groupMembers=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);


        groupSoap.addProperty("groupid","1");
        groupMembers.addProperty("Id","29");
        groupMembers.addProperty("Id","36");
        groupSoap.addProperty("groupMembers",groupMembers);


        PropertyInfo receiverMemberid = new PropertyInfo();
        receiverMemberid.setName("reciverMemberId");
        receiverMemberid.setValue(groupSoap);
        receiverMemberid.setType(groupSoap.getClass());
        myObject.addProperty(receiverMemberid);

        PropertyInfo memberId=new PropertyInfo();
        memberId.setName("MemberId");
        memberId.setValue(Integer.parseInt(senderId));
        memberId.setType(PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(memberId);

        PropertyInfo message=new PropertyInfo();
        message.setName("MESSAGE");
        message.setValue(messageText);
        message.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(message);

        PropertyInfo createDate=new PropertyInfo();
        createDate.setName("CREATEDDATE");
        createDate.setValue(dateNow);
        createDate.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(createDate);

        PropertyInfo isUrgent=new PropertyInfo();
        isUrgent.setName("isUrent");
        isUrgent.setValue(isUrgentFlag);
        isUrgent.setType(PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(isUrgent);

        PropertyInfo predifMessage=new PropertyInfo();
        predifMessage.setName("Predifnemessage");
        predifMessage.setValue("Hello");
        predifMessage.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        myObject.addProperty(predifMessage);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(myObject);
        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try
        {
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SoapWebServices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SoapWebServices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
        try
        {
            SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            return result.toString();
        }
        catch (SoapFault ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SoapWebServices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Ok if anyone have problem then let me know

Comment: I appreciate your answer,, but i need your help pls. refer below this link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198017/pass-arraylist-data-into-soap-web-service-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198017/pass-arraylist-data-into-soap-web-service-in-android) how can i pass arraylist data into SOAP service?

Comment: i have tried your answer its not working dude.. plz check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758106/passing-array-of-parameter-in-json-format-to-soap-web-service