# How to pass a String array to a webservice using soap libraries?

Tags: android, web-services, xml-serialization, android-ksoap2, arrays

I need to pass a a string array to a predefined webserivce designed to accept an array of string values. However when I create a soap envelope and set *array.class* or *string.class* properties to the request it throws a **serialization error**.

Any suggestions for the above? What should be the suggested data type or method to work around the same.

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

    PropertyInfo p1 = new PropertyInfo();
    p1.setName("items");
    p1.setValue(results);
    p1.setType(String.class); // else Array.class.
    request.addProperty(p1);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        httpTransport.debug = true;
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                       // throws an error in the above.

        result = httpTransport.responseDump;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518651/pass-array-using-web-services-in-ksoap2

Comment: why you want to pass array?

Comment: Check out this example : http://www.oguzozkeroglu.com/android-webservisten-donen-ic-ice-yapidaki-xmlin-parse-edilmesi/

Comment: @SagarMaiyad, what sort of a question is that? I want to because I have to.

Comment: @Raghunandan, thats the closest to what I was looking for, I could give you a useful upvote if you put the same in an answer, thank you!

Comment: @GarimaTiwari you can upvote any one of my answers by visiting my profile if the answer helps to show your appreciation. What i posted was link. so i can't post the link as an answer

Comment: @Garima then pass with same property until size of array.

Comment: @Raghunandan, just did!

Comment: @SagarMaiyad, I dont even get what you're trying to say but thank you for your time all the same.

Comment: @GarimaTiwari glad the link helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue with the KSOAP2 for Android library, which at the moment simply doesn't support arrays. The issue description is [here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=19).

A third-party patch, solution and an example can be found [here](http://people.unica.it/bart/ksoap2-patch/).

Look on these link, You can find your answer on that.

Comment: :need your help pls.refer this link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198017/pass-arraylist-data-into-soap-web-service-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198017/pass-arraylist-data-into-soap-web-service-in-android) how can i pass arraylist data to SOAP service in android ?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass parameter name and value like this in loop :

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
for (int i=0; i<itemId.length; i++){
    request.addProperty("itemID",itemId[i]);
}
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Just pass parametername and item value in loop using request.addProperty