# Java serialization error while sending byte array to webservice

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I am getting an error:  `Java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize : -119` while executing call method in `HttpTransportSE`.

I have tried both adding object directly:

```
public String UploadPhotoCall(byte[] imageContent)
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(_wsdlTargetNamespace, _operation);
request.addProperty("imageContent", imageContent);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(_soapAddressLocation);
Object response = null;
try{
httpTransport.call(_action, envelope);
response = envelope.getResponse();
}
catch(IOException ex){
response = ex.toString();
}
catch(Exception ex){
response = ex.toString();
}
```

and after reading topic [Pass Array using Web services in Ksoap2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518651/pass-array-using-web-services-in-ksoap2)
I tried this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(_wsdlTargetNamespace, _operation);
PropertyInfo propertyImage = new PropertyInfo();

SoapObject soapImage = ByteArrayTransform(imageContent);
propertyImage.setValue(soapImage);
propertyImage.setType(soapImage.getClass());
propertyImage.setName("imageContent");
request.addProperty(propertyImage);


public SoapObject ByteArrayTransform(byte[] image){
SoapObject soapImage = new SoapObject(_wsdlTargetNamespace, _operation);
Log.i(_TAG, "byte array transform begins");
for (int i =0; i < image.length; i++){
    soapImage.addProperty(Integer.toString(i), image[i]);
}
return soapImage;
}
```

But it still doesn't help. Can anyone show me, how to do it in a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I managed to resolve the problem. 
Adding byte array to request works in both methods, they just lacked one statement after SoapObject has been added to envelope:

```
new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
```

I hope someone finds it useful.