# passing Array of parameter in json format to SOAP web service?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, soap

I need to pass this Array of parameter to Ksoap webservice in android. This is my soap action.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <get_info xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <terms>
        <tc_id>string</tc_id>
        <tc_name>string</tc_name>
        <st_id>string</st_id>
      </terms>
    </get_info>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I Tried like this but i am not getting any response from server

**java**

```
public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/get_info";
 public final String OPERATION_NAME = "get_info";
 public final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
 public final String SOAP_ADDRESS ="http://192.168.0.116/Teachers/backend.asmx?op=get_info";
 SoapObject request = null, 
 objMessages = null;
 Object response = null;
 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;

 String result = null;



 // MethodName variable is define for which webservice function will call
 public String passdetails(String MethodName) {
  SoapObject res = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

  res.addProperty("tc_id","11");
  res.addProperty("tc_name","xxx");
  res.addProperty("st_id","1");

  System.out.println("request==="+res);
  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(OPERATION_NAME,"terms");
  request.addProperty("terms",res);


  System.out.println("terms==="+request);

  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.dotNet = true;

  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

  HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
  Object response = true;
  try {
   httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
   response = envelope.getResponse();
   String result123=response.toString();
   System.out.println("result123=="+result123);
  } catch (Exception exception) {
   response = exception.toString();
  }
  return response.toString();
 }
```

I dont know where i am wrong. i searched lot regrading this but i cant find a proper solution. thanks in adavance

Comment: quick question: you are providing `MethodName` as argument to the function but haven't you used it anywhere?

Comment: @MehulJoisar `MethodName` used to call this service from my another class

Comment: @MehulJoisar can you help me for above json format

Answer (score 0):

```
 request.addProperty("img",ba1);
 request.addProperty("uname",username);
 request.addProperty("albumname",al);
 request.addProperty("imagename",uniqueID);              

 //Declare the version of the SOAP request

 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);                

 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

 envelope.dotNet = true;



 try {

       HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);                     

       //this is the actual part that will call the webservice

       androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                     

       // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

       SoapObject result1 = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;



       if(result1 != null)

       {
          alertbox("Message!", "Image Uploaded successfully");

       }

       else

       {

          alertbox("Message!", "No Internet Connection!");

       }

 } catch (Exception e) {

       e.printStackTrace();

 }
```

Comment: i am not passing image and all. i just passing string values in above json format. can you help me like that format